# Do I have to encode http header into JSON?

Tags: json, http

I am designing a http server. I want to encode the body of http message into JSON.
I know that a http message contains a header and a http body.
I already encode everything into JSON format.
How about the http header? Do I have to encode http header into JSON as well?

Comment: I'd probably create a `headers` object that key/value maps the header names to their values. I don't understand what you're asking very well though.

Comment: I really mean no offense, but if you have to ask this, you perhaps don't want to be writing an HTTP server. I mean: if your server sends JSON-encoded headers back (how do you encode key-value pairs, like a JSON-array?), how is a client following the HTTP spec going to interpret those?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to encode http header into JSON as well?

**Absolutely not.** Not only don't you *have* you, you *must* not. The headers describe the body, and must follow [the standard for HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#General_format), which has nothing to do with JSON.